# Manager field should be auto populated when we select application in service catalog

Tags: servicenow

In category maps table I have created application and application manager field. For each application I have provided manager in application manager field.. In service portal when we select application then manager field should auto populate.

```
function onChange(control, oldValue, newValue, isLoading) {
if (isLoading ) {
//alert("manager");

}
var user=new GlideAjax("application",doAlert);
function doAlert(user){
g_form.setValue("u_application_manager",user.u_application_manager);

}
//Type appropriate comment here, and begin script below

}`
```

`

I have been struck here